# Read a byte starting from a specific bit in a file - C#

Tags: c#, byte, bit-shift, bit

I need to read a byte from a .bin but starting from the specific bit, for example:

If I have this two bytes:

```
01010111 10101100
```

The program should be able to read from any bit, let's say starting in bit number 3 (or index 2):

```
01[010111 10]101100
```

And the result should be 01011110

I can read a byte starting from any bit except when the starting bit is the one at the end of a byte: 0101011[1 ...] //returns something different..

my code is:

```
byte readByte(int indexInBits, byte[] bytes)
    {
        int actualByte = (indexInBits+1)/8;
        int indexInByte = (indexInBits)%8;
        int b1 = bytes[actualByte] << indexInByte;
        int b2 = bytes[actualByte+1] >> 8 - indexInByte;
        return (byte)(b1 + b2);
    }
```

What is wrong with it?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify `I can read a byte starting from any bit except when the starting bit is the one at the end of a byte`. Do you mean that it does not work when the starting and ending bits are the same? Like `1000 0001`?

Comment: You could create a BitArray, Convert it into a string and then just use the SubString method?! Just convert it back then...

Comment: `int actualByte = (indexInBits+1)/8` returns 1 for indexInBits == 7. But the 7th bit is still in the 1st byte, so actualByte should be 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
byte ReadByte(int index, byte[] bytes)
{
    int bytePos = index / 8;
    int bitPos = index % 8;
    int byte1 = bytes[bytePos] << bitPos;
    int byte2 = bytes[bytePos + 1] >> 8 - bitPos;
    return (byte)(byte1 + byte2);
}
```

I couldn't verify this right now, but this should work as expected.

Comment: Minus implicitly precedes shift operator. So the brackets are redundant in "bytes[bytePos + 1] >> (8 - bitPos);"

Comment: I also thought the index is 0-based, because in the question it is mentioned "let's say starting in bit number 3 (or index 2):" - so bytePos is indeed (index + 1)/8 .. or is it not?

Comment: I thought if the index is 7, then 7/8 equals 0 (int), but 8/8 equals 1, which is the wrong byte.

Comment: yep, that actually works, I don't know why I had (index + 1), thanks!